# By grammar rules of recursive descent parser how can we validate the source string

Tags: parsing

If the following two input strings are inputed :

```
1)<id> + <id> * <id>
2) <id> * <id> <id>

E ::= T{+T}* 
T ::= V{*V}* 
V ::= <id>
```

Then by applying the above grammar rules of recursive descent parser how can we validate the above source string. 
What type of the error will be indicated by recursive descent parser ?

Thanks...

Comment: Is this kind of question typical for CS programs? I was bored to tears half way through reading it...

Comment: @Chaos Yes. It makes me want to shoot myself some times.

Answer (score 1):

Your grammar rules look like arithmetic infix notation.  [Pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com) (a Python parsing add-on module) has a built-in method for building parser expressions for this kind of notation, called `operatorPrecedence`.  Here is how a pyparsing parser would parse your two examples:

```
from pyparsing import operatorPrecedence, opAssoc, ParseException

expr = operatorPrecedence("<id>",
    [
    ('*', 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
    ('+', 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
    ])

tests = """\
<id> + <id> * <id> 
<id> * <id> <id>""".splitlines()

for t in tests:
    print t
    try:
        print expr.parseString(t, parseAll=True).asList()
    except ParseException,pe:
        print "parsing failed"
    print
```

Prints:

```
<id> + <id> * <id> 
[['<id>', '+', ['<id>', '*', '<id>']]]

<id> * <id> <id>
parsing failed
```

Hope this helps you in your studies.

Comment: Paul can you help me how to perform this example step-by-step according to the D M Dhamdhere Systems Programming book.. Instead of algorithm in Pascal or Java i want to see how does CSF is predicted and SSM is incremented thenafter...